# slow query LEFT OUTER JOIN Mysql

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

thanks can you help me please, I'm migrating an application and go to mysql 5.5 is very slow query returned thank you very much for your help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id AS row_id, t0.cc46_value AS f_264, t1.cc46_value AS f_265, t2.cc46_value AS f_266
FROM tc46_fields_values b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tc46_fields_values t0 ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t0.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
  AND t0.cc46_cc26_field_id = 264 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tc46_fields_values t1 ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t1.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
  AND t1.cc46_cc26_field_id = 265 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tc46_fields_values t2 ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t2.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
  AND t2.cc46_cc26_field_id = 266
WHERE b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id IN (5924,5925,5926,5927,5928,5929,5930,5931,5932,5933,5934,5935,5936,5937,5938,5939,5940,5941,5942,5943,5944,5945,5946,5947,5948,5949,5950,5951,5952,5953,5954,5955,5956,5957,5958,5959,5960,5961,5962,5963,5964,5965,5966,5967,5968,5969,5970,5971,5972,5973,5974,5975,5976,5977,5978,5979,5980,5981,5982,5983,5984,5985,5986,5987,5988,5989,5990,5991,5992,5993,5994,5995,5996,5997,5998,5999,6000,6001,6002,6003,6004,6005,6006,6007,6008,6009,6010,6011,6012,6013,6014,6015,6016,6017,6018,6019,6020,6021,6022,6023,6024,6025,6026,6027,6028,6029,6030,6031,6032,6033,6034,6035,6036,6037,6038,6039,6040,6041,6042,6043,6044,6045,6046,6047,6048,6049,6050,6051,6052,6053,6054,6055,6056,6057,6058,6059,6060,6061,6062,6063,6064,6065,6066,6067,6068,6069,6070,6071,6072,6073,6074,6075,6076,6077,6078,6079,6080,6081,6082,6083,6084,6085,6086,6087,6088,6089,6090,6091,6092,6093,6094,6095,6096,6097,6098,6099,6100,6101,6102,6103,6104,6105,6106,6107,6108,6109,6110,6111,6112,6113,6114,6115,6116,6117,6118,6119,6120,6121,6122,6123,6124,6125,6126,6127,6128,6129,6130,6131,6132,6133,6134,6135,6136,6137,6138,6139,6140,6141,6142,6143,6144,6145,6146,6147,6148,6149,6150,6151,6152,6153,6154,6155,6156,6157,6158,6159,6160,6161,6162,6163,6164,6165,6166)
```

Comment: You did not give nearly enough information for us to give you any specific help.

Comment: But what I can say is that often a slow query happens because you are missing indexes on important columns. Please run EXPLAIN on this query and output the results. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Did you really type out all those numbers? What about [between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)?

Comment: disulpen not giving more information and organizing the query to make it more understandable. the names of the fields are stored in codes is a unique table that stores the information that comes in different forms these are created by the user sequentially but then this example, if you can add or remove more fields. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure you have an index on the field "cc46_cc55_field_id_id".  In addition, don't use your list of almost 200 IDs... Since your version is all sequential, just use a BETWEEN clause..

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id AS row_id, 
      t0.cc46_value AS f_264, 
      t1.cc46_value AS f_265, 
      t2.cc46_value AS f_266 
   FROM 
      tc46_fields_values b 
         LEFT JOIN tc46_fields_values t0 
            ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t0.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
           AND t0.cc46_cc26_field_id = 264 
         LEFT JOIN tc46_fields_values t1 
            ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t1.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
           AND t1.cc46_cc26_field_id = 265 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN tc46_fields_values t2 
            ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t2.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
           AND t2.cc46_cc26_field_id = 266 
   WHERE 
      b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id  between 5924 and 6166
```

Comment: Rather horrid field names, I must say. Good answer, that aside ;P

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this twice. Once for supplying a good answer that is probably right (missing indexes are the prime reason for slow queries), and once for taking the time to reformat that godawful query.

Answer (score 0):

To see what indexes are used run

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT 
      b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id AS row_id, 
      t0.cc46_value AS f_264, 
      t1.cc46_value AS f_265, 
      t2.cc46_value AS f_266 
   FROM 
      tc46_fields_values b 
         LEFT JOIN tc46_fields_values t0 
            ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t0.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
           AND t0.cc46_cc26_field_id = 264 
         LEFT JOIN tc46_fields_values t1 
            ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t1.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
           AND t1.cc46_cc26_field_id = 265 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN tc46_fields_values t2 
            ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t2.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
           AND t2.cc46_cc26_field_id = 266 
   WHERE 
      b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id  between 5924 and 6166
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to this query instead:

```
SELECT b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id AS row_id, t0.cc46_value AS f_264, t1.cc46_value AS f_265, t2.cc46_value AS f_266 
FROM 
tc46_fields_values b LEFT OUTER JOIN tc46_fields_values t0 ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t0.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tc46_fields_values t1 ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t1.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tc46_fields_values t2 ON b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id = t2.cc46_cc55_field_id_id 
WHERE
t0.cc46_cc26_field_id = 264
AND
t1.cc46_cc26_field_id = 265
AND
t2.cc46_cc26_field_id = 266
AND
b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id IN (5924,5925,5926,5927,5928,5929,5930,5931,5932,5933,5934,5935,5936,5937,5938,5939,5940,5941,5942,5943,5944,5945,5946,5947,5948,5949,5950,5951,5952,5953,5954,5955,5956,5957,5958,5959,5960,5961,5962,5963,5964,5965,5966,5967,5968,5969,5970,5971,5972,5973,5974,5975,5976,5977,5978,5979,5980,5981,5982,5983,5984,5985,5986,5987,5988,5989,5990,5991,5992,5993,5994,5995,5996,5997,5998,5999,6000,6001,6002,6003,6004,6005,6006,6007,6008,6009,6010,6011,6012,6013,6014,6015,6016,6017,6018,6019,6020,6021,6022,6023,6024,6025,6026,6027,6028,6029,6030,6031,6032,6033,6034,6035,6036,6037,6038,6039,6040,6041,6042,6043,6044,6045,6046,6047,6048,6049,6050,6051,6052,6053,6054,6055,6056,6057,6058,6059,6060,6061,6062,6063,6064,6065,6066,6067,6068,6069,6070,6071,6072,6073,6074,6075,6076,6077,6078,6079,6080,6081,6082,6083,6084,6085,6086,6087,6088,6089,6090,6091,6092,6093,6094,6095,6096,6097,6098,6099,6100,6101,6102,6103,6104,6105,6106,6107,6108,6109,6110,6111,6112,6113,6114,6115,6116,6117,6118,6119,6120,6121,6122,6123,6124,6125,6126,6127,6128,6129,6130,6131,6132,6133,6134,6135,6136,6137,6138,6139,6140,6141,6142,6143,6144,6145,6146,6147,6148,6149,6150,6151,6152,6153,6154,6155,6156,6157,6158,6159,6160,6161,6162,6163,6164,6165,6166)
GROUP BY
b.cc46_cc55_field_id_id
```

instead of using distinct use group by.